# I deploy static files (html,css, js) and working good at gae but for php files gives 404 error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, app.yaml

My app.yaml as:

```
 runtime: php55
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /
 static_files: www/index.html
 upload: www/index.html

 - url: /(.*)
 static_files: www/\1
 upload: www/(.*)
```

as seen above static files are under www dir. and php files are under the vendor dir and its sub sirs. I have read all days doc. to understand this yaml file to able to understand but unfortunately not yet :) . So, html and all static files works perfect. but when ajax calls php with sending data to php. gives 404 error. It works good on local wamp server. main opening page is index.html under www . And its ok. All day I tested many variant to able to deploy php files. Not able yet.

```
mainProjectRoot>app.yaml ( only this file and two directory "www and vendor")
                www/index.html
                   /css
                   /js
                vendor/smsgonder.php
                      /mail.php
                      /../../more php files
```

At least I gave up to try more variant and I need help to set up app.yaml page. (except above variant all extra code I received always error and no deployment) 
Any help will be much appretiated. Thanks in advance !

final app.yaml is

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 2
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: vendor/\1

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

[image]

**EDIT**
this is final app.yaml ... (for a while I have deployed php files and some are were woring . But again for some php I receive "POST 500 error " 
in case I like to share final app.yaml file here.

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 2
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*).php 
  script: \1.php

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. How could be :)) I spent 5-6 days just for deploying finished app :)'

Comment: You should ask new questions for new issues, this post has already morphed too many times.

Answer (score 1):

add this immediately after handlers:

```
- url: /(.*)\.php$
  script: vendor/\1.php
```

This will serve all request ending with .php to the php files within the vendor folder

Comment: Thank you very much but this time gives another error: unknown url handler type. ( I can not share screen capture) But I will try to write down.

Comment: note the spacing..... your app.yaml file should have 2 spaces before static_files and upload lines

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand you very well. You mean space in app.yaml file or ?

Comment: I edit above final app.yaml as your info. Please check above !?

Comment: Last 3 days I am trying to deploy my locally working site to gae. And still could not find a solution, I tried your offer and also with many many other ways. Its working perfect in my local wamp server. Even I could not able to run on locally dev_appserver.py as shown in tutorials. all files deployed except php at another dir. ! Please let me know if you have some more idea. :))

Comment: not sure why, will need a close inspection on your source directory to see why

Answer (score 1):

The handlers section for PHP scripts following the documentation [Example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#example) (works for `vendor` subdirectories as well):

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

**Note: indentation matters!**

Comment: Thank you Dan, but I tried this and doesn't work only. :( well, please give me full code if you could. !

Comment: I just fixed the indentation in your final `app.yaml`, see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41512218/revisions

Comment: Dan, thank you very much but again php files didin't uploaded. I tested both your code - url: /(.+\.php)$  . also Lawrence's above :- url: /(.*)\.php$.

Comment: All html, js other static files are ok. and works. log files says 404. either when I start website, gives same error at published site.

Comment: Did you understand the code indentation note and checked that the `app.yaml` file indentation is OK? To verify check a single `.php` file which doesn't reference other such files (to ensure the 404 is not caused by some other missing file)`. Maybe paste in the question the exact and *complete* error message

Comment: Yes, at least :)) Thank you very much...  I didn't know this was so important. :) But unfortunately I could not upload the files all !  php files still waiting me. Its works on local wamp server problem free.

Comment: Please check the link below above code. I tryed to upload a screen shot.

Comment: Aha, your request paths actually include the `vendor/` prefix, I'll update the answer. BTW, you shouldn't post text as images, you should copy/paste it into the post (and format it accordingly).

Comment: Dan, it is not text, I tried to copy paste the command prompt result. But not possible. so I made screen shot&cropped . then I uploaded as screenshot picture. under  vendor dir. there are 3 more dire deep in this dir. the tree under vendor is: \vendor\iyzico\iyzipay-php\samples (local dir map)